# Check if all inputs are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, onkeyup

I have multiple inputs on my page, when any them are filled, an "info div" appears on the side;
Now if all the inputs are manually cleared (on keyup), I need to hide that "info div".

How can I check (on keyup) that all of the inputs are empty at the same time?

Cheers

Comment: show us how you've made the info div appear

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Loop through all the inputs, and if you get to a non-empty one you know they're not all empty. If you complete your loop without finding one, then they *are* all empty.

```
function isEveryInputEmpty() {
    var allEmpty = true;

    $(':input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            allEmpty = false;
            return false; // we've found a non-empty one, so stop iterating
        }
    });

    return allEmpty;
}
```

You might want to 'trim' the input value before comparing (if you want to treat an input with just whitespace in it as empty). You also might want to be more specific about which inputs you're checking.

Comment: You can short cut the loop and return as soon as on input field is filled in, like `if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            return false;
        }`

Comment: @dsuess Updated. Thanks. (Although your example isn't quite enough: we can't `return false` the outer function from inside the inner one! We instead set `allEmpty = false`, then return `false` to tell `$.each` to stop iterating.)

Answer (score 3):

**Simple solution (ES6) Without jQuery**

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <input id="input1" />
  <input id="input2" />
  <input id="input3" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('btnCheckEmpty').addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (isEveryInputEmpty())
            alert('empty');
        else
            alert('not empty');
});


const isEveryInputEmpty = () => {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.container input');
    
    for (const input of inputs)
        if (input.value !== '') return false;
    
    return true;
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/urjtxe6c/10/)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without jQuery?

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy Good idea. I've edited my code.